# Creating a mysql Table from another Table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance

Here is my problem: I have a table with relations between people and objects.

```
Table logs

| id | user_id | object_id |
----------------------------
| 1  |  25488  |   54879   |
----------------------------
| 2  |  25488  |   54880   |
----------------------------
| 3  |  35487  |   54880   |
----------------------------
```

And I want to make a new table where each row is a user and each column is a object. If the user has a relation to the object I will input 1, if not 0.

```
Table User

|  id  | user_id  | o54879  |  o54880  | o87984  | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
|  1   |  25488   |   0     |     1    |    0    | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
|  2   |  35487   |   0     |     1    |    1    | ...
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I did the work with java but it is very slow. Creating the table is fine, but then I loop over every user and create the correct sql query (as a String). So each time, I make a query to extract the data and another to input the data in the new table. I have 100 000 user in the database so It will take a while.

Is there a faster way to acheve this, with less transactions to the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you have the destination table, then you know the list of objects you need.

This process is called pivoting a table.  In MySQL you need to do this explicitly.  Here is an example using aggregation:

```
insert into table2(user_id, o54879, o54880, . . .)
    select user_id,
           max(object_id = 54879),
           max(object_id = 54880),
           . . . 
    from logs
    group by user_id;
```

EDIT:

This uses a MySQL convention that `0` is false and `1` is true.  The above logic is equivalent to:

```
max(case when object_id = 54879 then 1 else 0 end),
max(case when object_id = 54880 then 1 else 0 end),
```

Sometimes, I prefer the explicit `case` statement, because that is standard SQL.  Sometimes, I prefer the MySQL convention because it does simplify the code (at the expense of making it slightly less readable for non-programmers).

Comment: thank you, I think this is what I need. If there is no object 54879 for the current user, the max will be 0?